# Передвижение фрагментов в Android

Tags: java, android

Есть два фрагмента master/details. Хочу сделать анимацию перехода с одного фрагмента в другой. Например после нажатия на кнопку cabins фрагмент Next должен переехать на его место(сместиться влево), а вместо него появился другой фрамент. Если говорить простым языком то надо поменять местами фрагменты используя анимацию.

Разметка:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/master_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Код:

```
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .remove(masterFragment)
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left)
                .commit();

        manager.executePendingTransactions();

        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(MASTER_CONTAINER, masterFragment)
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
                .commit();

        manager.executePendingTransactions();
```

[image: Фрагменты]